# How to specify a column for Prediction in Haystack?

Tags: python, rename, opensearch, nlp-question-answering, haystack

I am using an `OpenSearchDocumentStore` to store my data an feed it to my Haystack pipeline, the data includes uuids and other information, that are not relevant for the prediction but need to stack in the `DocumentStore` (I was told). Now I wonder if there is a way or need to specify a special Inputtext "column" for the retriever and reader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other information that are not relevant for retrieval should stay in the `meta` field of Documents. For example you could create documents like:

```py
doc = Document(
    content="this is relevant for retrieval", 
    meta={"uuid": "1234",  "comment": "this won't be used for retrieval"}
)
```